# responsive navbar not showing when resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

When altering the size of the browser window, If the navbar is closed and I go from mobile view to desktop the navbar remains in its closed state and is no longer visible.

If I do the above but after triggering the navbar to open and then alter the size of the browser window the navbar remains visible.

how can I make sure the navbar is always visible when viewing in desktop?

this is the full code lifted from my project:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $( "#navButton" ).click(function() {
    $( ".navigation" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
  });
  
  });
```

```css
/* nav */
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; 
  background-color: #333333;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: #444444;
  color: #61D6D6;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  
  .navigation li {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .navigation {
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: none;
  }
  
  #navButton {
    display: block;
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
    <div class="masthead">
      <div class="order-1 logoBox">
        <img alt="" src="images/logoPH.png" style="width: 50px; height: auto;">
      </div>
      <div class="order-2 item-grow-2">
        <div class="title"><h2>Lorem ipsum</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="order-2 item-grow-1 navMenuBox">
        <div id="navButton"><p><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> <br><span>menu</span></p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a class="active" href="#">sed do eiusmod</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">adipisicing</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">elit</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">consectetur</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: this i a common issue i face with responsive menu but i stop bothering about it simply because visitor will not play by resizing window and close the menu and then resize again. So i guess it's not really an issue but a particular case of usage

Comment: yes i agree that its not going to be a common issue but i still consider it a issue i would like to fix. If a visitor simply places two windows along side each other when multitasking and then increases the size again when finished it could trigger this issue.

Comment: in this case the only solution is to have a listener to window resize, and when on desktop you show the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideToggle` applies the `display:none` to `style` attribute of the element so you can't override that with the stylesheet, so you have to listen for the resizing event of the window and display the menu accordingly, here's a fiddle :   https://jsfiddle.net/5xr41460/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#navButton").click(function() {
    $(".navigation").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
  });
  $(window).on('resize', function() {

    if ($(this).width() > 800) {
      $('.navigation').css({
        'display': 'flex'
      });
    } else {
      $('.navigation').css({
        'display': 'none'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use on window resize in javascript to check viewport width and change your styles.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

or with jquery

```
$(window).resize(function () { /* do something */ });
```